# Asynchronous FIFO code advice - VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga, fifo

All the codes I've found generate me some errors. My FPGA manufacturer FIFO's when I try to read and write at the same time it create me problems in simulation and also I can't modify it or adapt to another FPGA.

Can someone advice me an already written Asynchronous FIFO (2 Clock FIFO) code in VHDL, possibly already used without problems?

I need the possibilty to read and write at the same time with 2 different clocks.

Answer (score 0):

Our [PoC Library](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC) has a cross-clock FIFO called [PoC.fifo.ic_got](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/fifo/fifo_ic_got.vhdl). (ic = independent clocks)

This FIFO can be configured in size and width. You can also chose to synthesize it with LUT-RAM or BlockRAM/altsyncram. Depending on the chosen vendor settings, it will use device specific code to improve carry-chain mapping or otherwise use a generic description.

This FIFO requires other modules and packages from PoC Library like [PoC.utils](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/common/utils.vhdl), [PoC.mem.ocram.*](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/mem/ocram/) or [PoC.arith.counter_gray](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/arith/arith_counter_gray.vhdl).

This FIFO was tested on several devices:

- Altera: Cyclone III, Startix-II/IV
- Xilinx: Spartan-3, Virtex-5/6/7, Kintex-7

Feel free to test it on other devices :).

Comment: Thank you, but it's seems really complex. Since I'm new at vhdl coding I don't know how to add libraryes and make code work. Can you help me?

Comment: Using cross-clock modules is never easy, but if you are used to normal FIFOs like `PoC.fifo.cc_got`, it's not so difficult to switch to the `ìc_got` implementation. We are working on a more detailed documentation: general usage, interface descriptions and examples, but this takes time... Please contact me directly by email. See the [AUTHORS](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/AUTHORS)-file for my contact information. Please, not which toolchain you are using: Xilinx ISE, Vivado or Altera Quartus-II.

Comment: Depending on your tool, there should be a way to assign source files to a VHDL library.